# Format one column and get rest of all column by one select

Tags: mysql

I am curious that, is there any method to get all column without the write rest of all.

Like so :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(START_DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') * FROM CUSTOMER;
```

What I want to do, format a single column and get all columns via one select. The reason is that, there are so many columns in the table which I do not want to write all of them each SELECT!

Comment: This is *bad practice*.  What if your schema changes?  Your application should *always* name the columns that it wishes to select.

Comment: right @eggyal but I need all columns from the table so it's not big deal right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRy :

```
SELECT customer.*, DATE_FORMAT(START_DATE, '%d.%m.%Y')  FROM CUSTOMER;
```